# How to build classifier chain where each binary classifier is a Keras's neural network?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

Although, Scikit learn support Classifier Chain for multi-label classification ([documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html#sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain)), the document does not provide example for building a chain in which individual binary classifiers are neural network that are build by using Keras. Could you please provide an example of this.
Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean an ensemble of neural networks?

Comment: Yes that is what I want